# Batch upload to YouTube - ASP.NET 4 C#

Tags: c#, asp.net, youtube, youtube-api, youtube.net-api

I've tried searching for the best method of doing batch uploads to YouTube but I've only found methods for uploading a single video to YouTube (which is fine, but not my situation).

I'd like to know the best method of uploading multiple videos to YouTube.  I noticed here:

http://code.google.com/apis/youtube/2.0/developers_guide_protocol.html#Uploading_large_batch_of_videos

That it needs to be spread out so you don't reach the quota.  However, I noticed that Batch Processing is available here:

http://code.google.com/apis/youtube/2.0/developers_guide_dotnet.html#Batch_processing

Is it possible to create a batch upload to YouTube using the request.Batch call?  Or is the only method to loop through the videos to be uploaded and upload them one at a time (given a 3-5 minute delay between each one)?  Has anyone done this and can offer some support?  If this is already discussed please let me know where and accept my apologies for not finding it in my search.

Thanks,
Mike

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like you need to wait between uploading videos.  The request.Batch call is for doing multiple operations on a **feed**, such as a playlist, or a user's favorites list.  You can't use it for uploading videos.

Comment: I was afraid of that.  Thanks for the feedback!